# Azure functions only max concurrent at the time

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-webjobssdk

I have a Azure Function that handles SharePoint operations. Due to throttling I only want 10 concurrent functions running at the time and always 10 functions concurrently. I was considering to use functions with an Azure Service Bus Queue. Is there any build in the Azure platform to achieve this? Service Bus is not a requirement, so if other hubs or queues are better for this. I have looked in the Azure UI and havent found anything on the service bus side or function.

**Test and observations:**

I created a test with no success. I have created and deployed a functions that sleeps for 20 secs and then write a document to Cosmos DB:

```
[FunctionName("SleepFunction")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("provision", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");

    string EndpointUrl = "https://kk-db-governance-engine.documents.azure.com:443/";
    string PrimaryKey = "xx";
    var docClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);
    var result = docClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("kk-governance", "test-function-concurrency"), new Run());

}
```

Functions app.settings:
[image]

If I add 10 messages to the queue, 10 documents are added to the database concurrently. I would expect that only 3 at the would be added with 20 secs delayed. Setting the WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT in the app settings does not seem seem to work. Any suggestions?

---

I also tried the maxConcurrentCalls in the host.json file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "xxx",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xx",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "xx"
  },
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "maxConcurrentCalls": "3"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see on screenshot below I use consumption plan:
[image]

---

Answer:
I got following working:

"serviceBus": {
    "maxConcurrentCalls": 3
  }

Comment: When you mean 10 functions, you mean you want to max a maximum of ten concurrent calls to SP ???

Comment: Yes exactly. I have one single function, and I want 10 concurrent instances of that single function running at all time. So if I add 10000 messages to the queue, 10 instances will run concurrently until all messages has been processed.

Comment: As per this post https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/912#issuecomment-419608830, you can set this setting 
 `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to `1`. It will force having only one instance of your function app running. And then you can change the max concurrent call to 10 in the `host.json file`. I think both storage queues and servicebus queues should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, highly appreciated. I will give it a test and get back.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a sample host.json? There is tons of articles describing that this should be set, but I havent found a single sample. I tried: {
  "WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT": 3
} but this throws an error.

Comment: WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT should be app setting. just put this in the app settings in the portal

Comment: Also if you want to configure the `host.json` file, check out the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Comment: Hi @Thomas I tried your suggestion, but didn't seem to work. I have updated post with findings.

Comment: Hope this thread gives some insight - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2667

Comment: Thanks @Baskar. Is the conclusion then you cannot currently have x numbers of functions running without developing your own system?

Comment: @ThomasSegato,  the `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` control the number of function apps that are spin up. If you want to change the max concurrent call, you need modify the host.json and set the max concurrent call also .

Comment: check the `maxConcurrentCalls` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#host-json

Comment: @ThomasSegato I am not sure,  but I would wait for some official confirmation from Functions team.

Comment: OK, I will see if I can get an answer from them (the Microsoft team).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An answer can be found here: [Add Singleton support for Functions to ensure only one function running at a time](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/912#issuecomment-419608830)

1. If you're running on the consumption plan: To ensure you won't scale out to more than one instance, set this app setting:

   - `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` = `1`
2. To allow only X concurrent calls in this instance, you can specify this setting in the `host.json` file:

   `{
       "version": "2.0",
       "extensions": {
           "serviceBus": {
               "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
           }
       }
   }`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I tried your suggestion, with no luck. I added finding to my main post.

Comment: Have you tried with both settings: WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT  set to 1 andmaxConcurrentCalls set to 3 ?

Comment: Jeps, both andmaxConcurrentCalls  and is set to 3. I think it is an issue in the product see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json. I have just created a support case to get this clarified.

Answer (score 2):

For those who find a way to this question, the actual host.json structure has changed since the accepted answer.

To allow only X concurrent calls in this instance, you can specify this setting in the host.json is now:

```
"extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 1,
      "batchOptions": {
        "maxMessageCount": 1
      }
    }
  }
```